# Change date from 0-100 to dd-mm-yy

Tags: python, arrays, date, python-datetime

I have a column of dates from 0-100 where the values can repeat themselves several times, but the 0 is actually Aug 1st of 2018, how can I solve so this so 0 = dd-mm-yy (01-08-2018) and for the rest to continue that order being the last one (09-09-2018)

Example:

```
ID Sale Date
1 .  4     0
2 .  2     0
3 .  10    1
4 .  1     1
5 .  30    100
```

Comment: Please share your own attempt

Answer (score 0):

Use Aug 1st 2018 as "base", and add a `timedelta` to it. As demonstration:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

base = datetime(2018, 8, 1)

for d in range(101):
    date = base + timedelta(days=d)
    print(d, date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base date and the use timedelta in order to increase the number of days based on the value you have in the `Date` column:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
​
def update_date(row):
    return row.parsed_date + timedelta(days=row.Date)
​
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5],
    'Sale': [4 , 2 , 10, 1 , 30],
    'Date': [0, 0, 1, 1, 100],
})
​
df['parsed_date'] = datetime(2018, 8, 1, 0, 0)
df['parsed_date'] = df.apply(update_date, axis=1)
```

Would result in:

```
      ID    Sale    Date    parsed_date
0      1    4      0        2018-08-01
1      2    2      0        2018-08-01
2      3    10     1        2018-08-02
3      4    1      1        2018-08-02
4      5    30     100      2018-11-09
```